# flash hardware acceleration also in flex sdk?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3

in the adobe flash publish settings i spotted a setting called "Hardware acceleration" with these options:

- None
- Level 1 - Direct
- Level 2 - GPU

now my question is, if you dont use flash to compile your swf but rather flex sdk, can you also enable these accelerations?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware acceleration mode is set via an HTML parameter so it does not matter if you do not use the Flash IDE to compile the SWF.

> When you publish your SWF file, the HTML file that embeds it contains
>   a wmode HTML parameter. Choosing Level 1 or Level 2 hardware
>   acceleration sets the wmode HTML parameter to "direct" or "gpu"
>   respectively. Turning on hardware acceleration overrides the Window
>   Mode setting you may have chosen in the HTML tab of the Publish
>   Settings dialog box, because it is also stored in the wmode parameter
>   in the HTML file.

Source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7bcea.html

Also, you may find this interesting regarding the Hardware Acceleration settings:

http://blog.kaourantin.net/?p=74